# Cannot read all messages from RabbitMQ

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I create RabbitMQ listener:

```
$connection = new AMQPConnection(
    $AMQP_config['server'],
    $AMQP_config['port'],
    $AMQP_config['user'],
    $AMQP_config['password'],
    $AMQP_config['virtual_host']
);

$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->basic_qos(
    null,
    1,
    null
);

$channel->basic_consume(
    $AMQP_config['queue'],
    '',
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    array($this, 'CallbackResponse')
);

while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

---

```
public function CallbackResponse(AMQPMessage $msg)
{
    $response = json_decode($msg->body)->acopMessage;
    if ($response->reqMRef == $this->_request_reference) {
        $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
    }
}
```

I have 5 messages on my RabbitMQ server. But I receive only one callback, only one entering into CallbackResponse().

I want to check all messages from the queue, find the one I've sent, read it, so there will be 4 messages left.

What I doing wrong, why I receive only first message?

Using this: https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib

Comment: Any ideas? What it can be?

Answer (score 1):

[Your QoS is set to 1](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html). So RabbitMQ will only send one message at a time.

As you only ack the message you are expecting for, the first message you received which does not match you condition remains unack. Thus, RabbitMQ will not send new message.

So messages that do not match must be [unacked and requeued](https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html)

Comment: Yes, but if I add like this:

            $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_nack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);

It still read all messages from queue

Comment: What do you mean by `It still read all messages from queue` ?

Comment: Оne connection reads all messages and there no any messages for another consumer.

Comment: Try `$msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_nack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag'], false, true);`  `false` for non multiple and `true` to requeue

Comment: Thanks for advice, but unfortunately it`s not help. In my callback I always receive the same message with the same data for all messages in queue.